# Using "to do" twice in a sentence is correct?

Tags: repetition

Is it correct to use "to do" twice in a sentence? For example: is it correct to say "how to do that and when to do that is a problem" or should it be "how to do that and when doing that is a problem"?

Comment: If you want to combine them, you could write _how and when to do that is a problem_.

Answer (score 4):

Since ***How to do that*** and ***when to do that*** are simply nounal phrases, there is no harm in using them multiple times in the same sentence.

Indeed you could say ***How to do it, when to do it, and in what manner to do it, each present problems***.

Your alternative sentence does not make grammatical nor idiomatic sense